# SQL CTE from binded array parameter

Tags: c++, odbc, amazon-redshift, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I would like to use array parameter binding in SELECT like SQL statement, like in the following example (please note the `limit0` CTE)

```
WITH
    limit0(val)
    AS
    (
        SELECT * FROM (?)
    ),
    total(limit0val)
    AS
    (
        SELECT DISTINCT limit0.val
        FROM limit0
    )
SELECT total.limit0val
FROM total;
```

The input value of the `?` is an array of values and I would like to use these values as any other CTEs (filtering, joining on it, etc)
The problem is that I couldn't find a way to bind an array into a SELECT statement.

Can anybody help me, how to refactor this query?

Applied code stack:

1. c++
2. ODBC
3. Snowflake & Redshift compliance SQL

Reflect to the comments:

1. VALUES clause is not supported by Redshift (AFAIK)
2. Parameter array cannot be the part of the query, due to it can exceed the maximum query lenght

Answer (score 1):

You can't bind arrays, but you can create a delimited string and use the STRTOK_TO_ARRAY function to parse it to an array:

```
select strtok_to_array('MEMBER_1,MEMBER_2,MEMBER_3', ',') as MY_ARRAY;
```

You can specify the delimiter you want to use. You can then use a string bind variable like this:

```
select strtok_to_array(?, ',') as MY_ARRAY;
```

Comment: The problem with the concept to hard-code values into the query is that SQL limits the query size up to 1M character, so not a secure way to add them into the query.

Comment: The limit applies to compressed text size up to 1Mb and applies to bind variable and the text. The first code sample is only there to show how to send an array, not suggesting to hard code it. The string will be sent as a parameterized bind variable. You cannot send an array of arbitrary length as a bind variable, but you can send a concatenated string and use the strtok_to_array function.

Comment: which is thesame point I was trying to show, "not a 'here is exact code you can cut'n'paste' but here is tools you can combine to get where you want to go"

Answer (score 0):

So if we start with some SQL that works:

So array parameters could mean I will pass in arbitry array of values thus you want the SQL to be effectively:

```
WITH limit0(val) AS (
    SELECT * FROM VALUES (0),(1),(0),(1),(2)
), total(limit0val) AS (
    SELECT DISTINCT limit0.val 
    FROM limit0
)
SELECT total.limit0val
FROM total;
```

thus the input might be `(0),(1),(0),(1),(2)`
OR
you might mean I have an array that I pass as a single string value, and parse inside the SQL, thus:

```
WITH limit0(val) AS (
    SELECT try_to_number(t.value) FROM TABLE(split_to_table('0, 1, 0, 1,2', ',')) t
), total(limit0val) AS (
    SELECT DISTINCT limit0.val 
    FROM limit0
)
SELECT total.limit0val
FROM total;
```

could be used and the input would be a single parameter `'0, 1, 0, 1,2'`

The latter seems easer to me.

I also assume you have read the [ODBC Binding Parameters to Array Variables For Batch Inserts](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/odbc-using.html#binding-parameters-to-array-variables-for-batch-inserts) help.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I have read the link, where also an "INSERT" statement is in use that consume array parameter, but I have to select values that match an input criteria set (array of parameters).